# Teams Message Extension: Embedding Content from Tab App into Task Module with Authentication

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, microsoft-teams, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-teams-js

I have created a Tab App in Teams. Now I want to make a dialog from one tab accessible via a Message Extension App. This works partially now through embedding the contentUrl of the specific tab as an iFrame in the Task Module of the Message Extension like here: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/action-commands/create-task-module?tabs=dotnet#create-a-task-module-with-an-embedded-web-view](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)
. The issue is the authentication. Api Calls won't work and the dialog is not able to retreive or send data.

In the manifest.json of the Tab App are the contentUrls of the tabs in the "staticTabs" section:

```
  "staticTabs": [
    {
      "entityId": "dashboard",
      "name": "Dashboard",
      "contentUrl": "https://cdne-stcsfeedbackuidev.azureedge.net/tabs/dashboard.html?app.locale={locale}&page.subPageId={subEntityId}&app.theme={theme}",
      "scopes": [
        "personal"
      ]
    }
  ],
```

I gave the dialog a specific Route via React Router so that you can access the dialog via subPageId. This works fine.

The Problem is, if you access the contentUrl, you won't be authenticated and API calls to the Graph API and own API won't work. This issue does not go away if I embed the tab via contentUrl in a Task Module for the Message Extension to give it a Teams Context:

```
  public async handleTeamsMessagingExtensionFetchTask(
    context: any, 
    action: any
  ): Promise<any> {
    return {
      task: {
        type: 'continue',
        value: {
          width: 925,
          height: 925,
          title: 'Feedback Dialog',
          url: "https://2e70-37-201-241-91.ngrok.io/feedbackDialog.html",
          fallbackUrl: "https://cdne-stcsfeedbackuidev.azureedge.net/tabs/dashboard.html?page.subPageId=feedbackDialog"
        }
      }
    };
  }
```

Directly embedding the url like in "fallbackUrl" will result in an empty Task Module so I embedded the Url in a  like this in feedbackDialog.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Hello World Feedback!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://statics.teams.microsoft.com/sdk/v1.7.0/js/MicrosoftTeams.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            microsoftTeams.initialize();
            microsoftTeams.getContext((context) => {
                console.log(context);
                microsoftTeams.authentication.getAuthToken({
                    successCallback: (token) => {
                        console.log(token);
                    },
                    failureCallback: (reason) => {
                        console.error(reason);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        <div style="padding:50px;">
            <iframe id="feedbackDialog" width="800" height="800", frameBorder="0" 
            src="https://cdne-stcsfeedbackuidev.azureedge.net/tabs/dashboard.html?page.subPageId=feedbackDialog"></iframe>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The dialog gets displayed in the Task Module this way like if I open the contentUrl in the browser directly. But the Authentication does not work. The Teams context can be retreived but all API calls return with the Error: "Error: SDK initialization timed out".

Is there a simple way for me to authenticate the user here because this runs in Teams as a MessageExtension App and the embedded content in the Task Module comes from a Teams Tab App. Or do I need to manually implement something using MSAL?

Comment: Could you please provide the sample code repo you are referring with repro steps and manifest so that we can check once from our end?

Comment: Need details here to reproduce the issue